# why postgres written by c not c++? is c has better performance or just a history reason?

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, pg

I am learning postgresql source code

But I am curious about why situations is not written in c++.

Is it a history reason(just choose a c language)

Or maybe in some situations c has better performance than c++.

The world’s most popular databases, including PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle Database are coded in C

Comment: The world’s most popular databases, including Oracle Database, MySQL, MS SQL Server, and PostgreSQL, are coded in C

Comment: Are you hoping that the original Postgres authors happen to frequent this site?

Comment: i hope the original authors to answer, that may have another view to see the question

Comment: The code was originally written in Lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a *long* history. It was conceived as a successor to Ingres, which goes back to the 1970s. Although the first version of PostgreSQL was released to the public in 1996, papers about it were published as early as 1986, only a year after Stroustrup published *The C++ Programming Language* and the first C++ compiler became available.

So at the time the early versions of PostgreSQL were developed, C++ didn't properly exist yet.